# Interpolation over non smooth data

Tags: interpolation

I have the following test data, and I need to interpolate over these data. I attempted to use `Interpolation`. However, the interpolated data are not smooth enough. Is there any better way to interpolate my data?

```
a = Table[DATA[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 35}];
b = Table[DATA[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 35}]; 
xx = Interpolation[Transpose[{a, b}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

{{1., 0.}, {1.3432, 57.4713}, {1.39448, 344.828}, {1.41026, 
  459.77}, {1.43195, 574.713}, {1.45168, 632.184}, {1.4714, 
  747.126}, {1.49901, 747.126}, {1.53057, 862.069}, {1.54832, 
  977.011}, {1.57791, 919.54}, {1.59763, 1034.48}, {1.61933, 
  1091.95}, {1.63708, 1149.43}, {1.6568, 1379.31}, {1.67258, 
  1551.72}, {1.69428, 1839.08}, {1.71992, 2126.44}, {1.73964, 
  2471.26}, {1.78107, 3103.45}, {1.7929, 3850.57}, {1.80868, 
  4540.23}, {1.81854, 5344.83}, {1.83235, 6206.9}, {1.84221, 
  7011.49}, {1.86193, 8045.98}, {1.87179, 10057.5}, {1.87771, 
  10747.1}, {1.88363, 11781.6}, {1.89546, 12988.5}, {1.89941, 
  14712.6}, {1.90335, 15517.2}, {1.9073, 16034.5}, {1.90927, 
  16781.6}, {1.91124, 17528.7}}
```

Comment: How are you using `Interplation`?

Comment: a = Table[DATA[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 35}];
b = Table[DATA[[i, 2]], {i, 1, 35}];

xx = Interpolation[Transpose[{a, b}], InterpolationOrder -> 1];

Comment: Please add this information to your post. Also add a comment about what it is that you got as a result and what you would have expected.

Comment: Interpolation will go through all the points, is that what you want? Or do you want a regression, i.e. a best fit to a model function?

Comment: yes i need it to go thorough all the points as smooth as possible.

Comment: Hi @user49047, I edited your question to make it easier to read (random matrices make it easier for us to try to help you), but fell free to rollback if you want.

Comment: After the edit I sugested I got some good looking results with InterpolationOrder -> 3, perhaps thats what you want?

Comment: @ i have already tried higher order interpolation on my test date. there are some physical meaning behind my test data and they are not some scattered data. for example the first column is stretch and second column is stress. so when i use Interpolation Order three  it will give me negative value of stress.

Comment: You can avoid the negative numbers if you take the log of the stress, and make an interpolation function for logstress vs stretch.  You then just exponentiate the interpolating function.  [Square root also works.]

Comment: Experimental data *always* has some uncertainty to it, so you should be doing a fit of some sort, requiring the fit to pass within tolerance of the points, not an interpolation that *exactly* hits the points.

Comment: @george2079 thats the next step as i will minimize norm of data - stress from  constitutive model

Comment: @Erich Mueller can you elaborate a bit how it can be beneficial ? because i will get obviously indeterminate results for my negative stress values.

Comment: Can you just delete the first data point, and then use normal Interpolation with order 3 to get something smoother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is fit (not interpolation) using a piecewise cubic function:

```
data = {{1.3432, 57.4713}, {1.39448, 344.828}, {1.41026, 
   459.77}, {1.43195, 574.713}, {1.45168, 632.184}, {1.4714, 
   747.126}, {1.49901, 747.126}, {1.53057, 862.069}, {1.54832, 
   977.011}, {1.57791, 919.54}, {1.59763, 1034.48}, {1.61933, 
   1091.95}, {1.63708, 1149.43}, {1.6568, 1379.31}, {1.67258, 
   1551.72}, {1.69428, 1839.08}, {1.71992, 2126.44}, {1.73964, 
   2471.26}, {1.78107, 3103.45}, {1.7929, 3850.57}, {1.80868, 
   4540.23}, {1.81854, 5344.83}, {1.83235, 6206.9}, {1.84221, 
   7011.49}, {1.86193, 8045.98}, {1.87179, 10057.5}, {1.87771, 
   10747.1}, {1.88363, 11781.6}, {1.89546, 12988.5}, {1.89941, 
   14712.6}, {1.90335, 15517.2}, {1.9073, 16034.5}, {1.90927, 
   16781.6}, {1.91124, 17528.7}}
np = 20
unk = Transpose[{Subdivide[Sequence @@ data[[{1, -1}, 1]], np - 1], 
    Table[Symbol["yi" <> ToString[i]], {i, np}]}];
NMinimize[(Interpolation[unk][data[[All, 1]]] - data[[All, 2]])^2 // 
   Total, unk[[All, 2]]];
fit = Interpolation[unk /. %[[2]]];

Show[{
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[fit[x], {x, data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}, PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image]

As you see it aims to be a smooth approximation without attempting to hit every one of the scattered points.

Note I dropped the very first point from the data as it was too far outlying and messed up the fit.

Comment: it looks promising after x=1.34 but still i am missing good chunk of the data from 1:1.34. lets say n=100;a= Table[1 + (1.91124 - 1)/n*i, {i, 0, n}]; b = Table[fit[x], {x, a}]; then you will see it needs to extrapolate between 1:1.34 which are some ridiculous values.

Comment: so collect more data..  seriously just do a linear interploation between the first two points.